# Are emails marked as junk in Outlook passed to the Exchange server to improve its spam filter?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, spam-prevention

I have been getting more spam emails to my corporate account recently. I have asked our Service Desk to block these at server level – so this is not the issue.

If I mark a message as junk in the Outlook client, are the rules passed up to our Exchange server to improve the spam filter globally?

Comment: I would say check with your Service Desk.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I did and they didn't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not used globally. Rules that you add are uploaded to Exchange and the rules check e-mails on the server (less load for your computer) but only for your account.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-the-Junk-Email-Filter-364853fe-095a-4563-b3ff-0b5b0ac7eeb3

It is of course possible for the Exchange admins to deploy global filters with Group Policies or Office Custimization Tool, if they use this there might be a process to report offenders and have a spam address added to their list.

Comment: Do you have any information on the global filters?

Comment: Sure, but that's quite an extensive topic perhaps more suited for ServerFault. This is a good place to start https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179183.aspx

Comment: I'll have a dig around in global filters and ask on ServerFault if i need any more information, thanks.